# Two separate SQL statements with the same data is returning different results

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do is send a list of domains to my php script (`$_POST['domains']`) and then fetch every employee from the table whose domain is similar.

Here's an example using a for loop to execute multiple queries. This is standard, but takes a lot longer:

```
    $domains = explode(",", $_POST['domains']);
    $returnObj = new stdClass();
    $employees = [];
    foreach($domains as $domain) {
        $domainLike = "%".$domain;
        $query = $conn_databank->prepare("SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE domain LIKE ?");
        $query->bind_param('s', $domainLike);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($employees, $row['employee_id']);
        }
    }
    $returnObj->employees = $employees;
    echo json_encode($returnObj);
```

Now, with one set of data I get around 3900 results, which is correct.

The other method I'm trying is by creating a dynamic prepared statement using `LIKE ? OR LIKE ?` which executes faster but doesn't return nearly as many results (around 950):

```
    $queryString = "SELECT employee_id FROM employee";
    $actualQuery = "SELECT employee_id FROM employee";
    $bindVariables = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($domains); $i++) {
        $domainLike = "%".$domains[$i];
        if($i == 0) {
            $queryString .= " WHERE (domain LIKE ?";
            $actualQuery .= " WHERE (domain LIKE '".$domainLike."'";
        }
        else {
            $queryString .= " OR domain LIKE ?";
            $actualQuery .= " OR domain LIKE '".$domainLike."'";
        }
        if($i == count($domains) - 1) {
            $queryString .= ")";
            $actualQuery .= ")";
        }
        array_push($bindVariables, $domainLike);
    }

    $variables = count(explode("?", $queryString)) - 1;
    $bindings = [];
    $bindString = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $variables; $i++)
        $bindString .= "s";
    array_push($bindings, $bindString);
    foreach($bindVariables as $variable)
        array_push($bindings, $variable);
    echo $actualQuery;
    $query = $conn_databank->prepare($queryString);
    call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($bindings));
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->get_result();
    $returnObj = new stdClass();

    $employees = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $employee = new stdClass();
        $employee->id = $row['employee_id'];
        array_push($employees, $employee);
    }
    $returnObj->employees = $employees;
    echo json_encode($returnObj);
```

Ignore the `$actualQuery` variable, that was just to see if it was building the query properly.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking here?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague without examples.  But, it is clear that one domain can match multiple `like` conditions.  For instance:  `xxx@gmail.com` will match both "mail.com" and "gmail.com".

You don't have sufficient information to tell if this is a problem.  So, one idea is to be sure that the domains are *complete*.  So, "@gmail.com" rather than "gmail" and using `email like concat('%', $domain)`.

That might not work, because you might need more flexibility (say, to match "gmail.co.uk").  If this is the case, then the `OR` is probably more correct because it does not contain duplicates.